# IDEA intellij how to stop constants reformatting?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok

I have class below and I would like to avoid constants reformatting inside of it. I've tried to use `formatter:off`, but there is no luck

```
public class Test {

    // @formatter:off
    private static final String TEST_FIRST_NAME = "firstname";
    private static final String TEST_SECOND_NAME = "secondname";

    public static final Test1 TEST1 = new Test1(TEST_FIRST_NAME);
    public static final Test2 TEST2 = new Test2(TEST_SECOND_NAME);
    // @formatter:on

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class Test1 {

        private String name;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class Test2 {

        private String name;
    }
}
```

After reformatting constant change the order to:

```
   // @formatter:off
    private static final String TEST_FIRST_NAME = "firstname";
    public static final Test1 TEST1 = new Test1(TEST_FIRST_NAME);
    private static final String TEST_SECOND_NAME = "secondname";
    public static final Test2 TEST2 = new Test2(TEST_SECOND_NAME);
    // @formatter:on
```

Markers are enabled[image]:

Please advice how to avoid this

Comment: What IDE version do you use? (Help | About)

Comment: Please export your IDE settings (File | Manage IDE Settings | Export Settings...) and upload them at https://uploads.jetbrains.com . Then write UploadID in the comments.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov, thank you for promt reply. I've just uploaded Upload id: 2021_07_16_WxyQmYJDGQ9At2hQ (file: settings.zip)

Comment: Try to uncheck "Rearrange code" under "Code | Reformat File".

Comment: @EgorKlepikov In that case constants keep unsorted, but there are few points regarding this:

1) I would like that rearrangement works for the rest of the file which is out of formatter:off section
2) I would like to have possibility to apply fix globally, not only for some specific file

Comment: I agree that this behavior can be inconvenient. Feel free to upvote/comment on the related request in YouTrack - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-131906 .

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable this feature. Settings -> Editor -> Code Style

[image: code formatting]

Comment: The option is enabled for me. I will update the question with this info

Comment: Oh, ok. I've checked, and I'm experiencing the same behavior as you are.